# Creating List View in Salesforce using Apex or Metadata

Tags: apex, metadata-api

I have tried to run following code in dev console and it ran successfully without any error but unfortunately it didn't created the list view even.

```
HTTP h = new HTTP();
HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'create');

String b = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
b += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
b += '<soapenv:Header>';
b += '<ns1:SessionHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
b += '<ns1:sessionId>' + UserInfo.getSessionId() + '</ns1:sessionId>';
b += '</ns1:SessionHeader>';
b += '</soapenv:Header>';
b += '<soapenv:Body>';
b += '<create xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
b += '<metadata xsi:type="ns2:ListView" xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
//This is the API name of the list view
b += '<fullName>Car__c.listView2</fullName>';
b += '<booleanFilter>1</booleanFilter>';
//Columns you want to display
b += '<columns>NAME</columns>';
b += '<columns>CREATED_DATE</columns>';
//Filterscope should be set to Everything for every one to be able to access this List view
b += '<filterScope>Everything</filterScope>';
// Enter the filter that you want to set
b += '<filters>';
b += '<field>NAME</field>';
b += '<operation>equals</operation>';
b += '<value>Mercedes </value>';
b += '</filters>';
b += '<label>Mercedes View</label>';
b += '</metadata>';
b += '</create>';
b += '</soapenv:Body>';
b += '</soapenv:Envelope>';

req.setBody(b);
req.setCompressed(false);
// Set this to org's endpoint and add it to the remote site settings.
req.setEndpoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/25.0');
HTTPResponse resp = h.send(req);
System.debug(resp.getBody());
```

Comment: What is the response of this line `System.debug(resp.getBody());`?

Comment: @manjit5190 It gives below response

< ? xml version = "1.0"
encoding = "UTF-8" ? > < soapenv : Envelope xmlns: soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns = "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" > < soapenv: Body > < createResponse > < result > < done > false < /done><id>04s2y000000GmadAAC</id > < state > InProgress < /state></result > < /createResponse></soapenv: Body > < /soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: So the deploy is in progress. We're you able to track it through the deployment status?